# close event NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I have an application, where a second `NSWindow` is opened by pressing a button. This new window is opened using `[NSApp runModalForWindow:<myWindow>]`. I want to be able to determine if the user closes the second window, in order to stop the modal.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are several ways to be notified when a window closes.

- You can observe `NSWindowWillCloseNotification` notifications from the second `NSWindow` object.
- You can implement `NSWindowDelegate` methods `windowShouldClose:` or `windowWillClose:`.
- You can subclass `NSWindow` and override the `performClose:` method.
- You can add a Close button to the window, and connect it to an action.

Without more information, it's hard to advise which of these or other options would work best for you.